# Wordpress is very slow 6 level hierarchical taxonomies (50.000 woocommerce product categories)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Anyone can help me to increase my wordpress speed.
I use woocommerce, in my site has 1 million products and 50K categories,
So my website going down when i'm use product edit admin page, or when i'm use anything connected hierarchical taxonomies.

Comment: Look at the slow query log to find out which queries are the problem, then try to optimize them. But really, you have more categories than amazon has on their country specific sites, but then only 20 products per category? What are you doing, and why are you doing it with WordPress?

Comment: i think problem not connected with wordpress taxonomy system,
i need to disable hierarchical preview in edit page, i think its can help me, but i already disable taxonomy meta box, but not helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change database table types from INNODB to MyISAM.
Or you can use Cloud database for performance.